# Debugging silverlight 3 in vs2008 after vs2010\silverlight 4 installed

Tags: visual-studio-2008, silverlight, silverlight-3.0, silverlight-4.0

I've installed vs2010 on my machine now it seems that I can't debug\run my silverlight 3 app in vs2008.  The debug play button (F5) is grayed out.  And when an exception is throw it says "Debugging resource strings are unavailable".

I feel like I read something about this somewhere but can't seem  to find it now. Also I can't just us vs2010 and target .net 3.5 b/c another develop I'm working only has vs2008.

Is this a known issue?  Are there any workarounds.

thanks.

Comment: You say that the Debug (F5) button is grayed out, do you mean on the Visual Studio toolbar?

Comment: Yes I mean if I select Debug from the toolbar the "Start debugging F5" option is disabled.

Comment: I have this problem too... Any solutions known?

Comment: Check these links might it help you :
http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/05/20/silverlight-and-visual-studio-2010-beta.aspx
http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2010/04/15/download-silverlight-4-released.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try re-installing [Silverlight 3 Tools for Visual Studio 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=9442b0f2-7465-417a-88f3-5e7b5409e9dd&displaylang=en).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the only thing that gets messed up when you try to use "old" versions of.. stuff.. on the new dev env. I recommend to set up a virtual machine where you put on Visual Studio with all it's companions (like SL3).

I guess this is a workaround - but there are other advantages developing on virtual machines, like backing up the whole thing or taking it with you on a usb stick...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is is that there are multiple versions of Silverlight, .NET, developer Silverlight, and the Visual Studio Tools, and only some of them are compatiblle.  Try downloading different runtimes and see what works.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have some code that is wrote in SL version 2? I had same problem when I uninstalled version SL2 and 3 and installed SL4. It was resolved when I un installed SL4 and installed SL2 and SL3 and then again installed SL4. Don't know the reason but this worked for me and my friends too.

Answer (score 0):

once you open a project of vs2008 in vs 2010 it asks to convert and if converted it can not be opened in vs 2008

unless these changes are made

http://blog.prabir.me/post/Downgrading-VS2010-solutions-to-VS2008.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Why not try loading up VS2008, then loading up your IE instance, then in VS2008, attach the debugger to the IE process?  Shouldn't that work?